# iOS Navigationbar changes color during animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uinavigationbar

I'm having a strange graphical issue in iOS 7 on both, Simulator and Device.

I call a segue from the storyboard programmatically after a cell in a table view has been pressed:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showTerminDetailView" sender:self];
```

Then I inflate some values:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showTerminDetailView"]) {
    Termin *termin = [self termineAtDate:self.currentday][[((TerminDayTableViewTableViewController *)self.terminTableViews[3]).tableView indexPathForSelectedRow].row];
    TerminDetailViewController *terminDetailViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
    terminDetailViewController.termin = termin;
}
```

}

The problem is that the right side of the navigation bar becomes darker during the animation:
[image: Normal navigation bar][image: Navigation bar during the animation]

Any help is welcome!

Comment: What on earth are you doing here: `Termin *termin = [self termineAtDate:self.currentday][[((TerminDayTableViewTableViewController *)self.terminTableViews[3]).tableView indexPathForSelectedRow].row];`???

Comment: Are you dumpster-diving into a stored view controller? That is extremely suspect. If you comment out that line (and don't set the destination's `termin`), does the problem go away?

Comment: @matt looks like he is just passing data between the view controllers

Comment: @Bot no it doesn't - he shouldn't have something called `self.terminTableViews` which is an array of view controllers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is normal behavior. iOS7 navigation bar is translucent by default so you can see what is beneath it. Your issue could be one of the following

- The controller is set to only show beneath the navigation controller.
- You have `self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;` on your pushed view controller so it is changing from translucent to non translucent
- You have `self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;` which is again moving the content down below which will make the nav controller not have content under it
- You have something showing in your pushed view controller behind the nav bar.

Comment: A combination of 'self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;' and 'self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;' in the original and the pushed view controller fixed it. Thanks!